# MLP prediction accuracy

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying out some machine learning exercises for practice as I still am new to this. I found a good problem to start, it was a bout classifying poker hands, I managed to create the following code and it works fine I managed to predict the test data hands.

```
import pandas as pnd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix

training_data = pnd.read_csv(".idea/train.csv")
print(training_data)
training_data['id'] = range(1, len(training_data) + 1)  # For 1-base index
print(training_data)

test_data = pnd.read_csv(".idea/test.csv")
result = pnd.DataFrame(test_data['id'])
print(result)
test_data = test_data.drop(['id'], axis=1)

training_datafile = training_data
labels = training_datafile['hand']
features = training_datafile.drop(['id', 'hand'], axis=1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
# Fit only to the training data
scaler.fit(training_datafile)
X_train = scaler.transform(training_datafile)
X_test = scaler.transform(training_datafile)
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100, 100))
mlp.fit(features, labels)
predictions = mlp.predict(test_data)
len(mlp.coefs_)
len(mlp.coefs_[0])
len(mlp.intercepts_[0])
result.insert(1, 'hand', predictions)
result.to_csv(".idea/ANNTEST.csv", index=False)
```

Now my question is what can I do to check how accurate this prediction was ?
The following are snippets of the data sets I used.

[Train data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKt4G.jpg)

[Prediction Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMyfx.png)

Help and guideance would be much appreciated !

Comment: You can simply use "accuracy_score(original_result, predicted_result)". See documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: yes, i have already tried that but I get the following error:
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: continuous-multioutput is not supported

Comment: What possible values can be present in `hand`? If its a continuous interval between 0 to some number, then you should probably try regression, not classification. In that case, try `mean_squared_error()`.

Comment: basically I have from 0-9 to classify the poker hands

Comment: Can you post the `predictions` output here?

Comment: I pasted an image on the output on the question just now :)

Comment: This is suspicious. You should post the code you used for accuracy as well as full stack trace of error.

Comment: Also, now that I am looking at your code more attentively, the X_train and X_test are not used anywhere. And they would be exact same, because you are using same command (`scaler.transform(training_datafile)`) on them

Answer (score 1):

Just use percentage of correct predicted results. Confusion matrix and table function are available in python.

suppose your test results is like follows 
***actual predicted***
A    A
**A    B**
B    B
**B    A**
B    B

so here we see two values does not match, so accuracy is 60% here